# Facebook authorization for DESKTOP applications using short/long lived tokens

Tags: facebook, oauth

I would like to add a new option to my application that allows users to post images to their Facebook albums or on the wall. As of now, the most unclear point is how to organize authorizaton process in the DESKTOP application. Official documentation says that I can use short-lived or long-lived access tokens. There is no any issue with getting short-lived access tokens, but I want my application to ask a user for login/password rarely.

I see 2 possible options.

**1) Use short-lived access tokens**

When a previous token has expired, I need to ask Facebbok for a new one, but for that I need user's login/password.

*Questions:*

1.1) Is it a good idea to store and encrypt somewhere on disk user's login/password and to ask Facebook for a new short-lived access token using user's credentials in the background (i.e. user won't see login form - this is hidden) ?

1.2) Is it a good idea to store and encrypt short-lived access token on disk to reuse it if a user just restarted application and token is still valid?

**2) Use long-lived access tokens**

This would be ideal for me. Even if access token has expired after 60 days, my desktop app will ask for a new one.

*Questions:*

2.1) Is it possible to get long-lived access token by DESKTOP application directly from Facebook? Is it needed to implement additional Web service for getting such token (I know that just server (not client app) can add app secret to request for long-lived token)?

2.2) Even if I able to get long-lived token from the Facebook directly, is it a good idea to store and encrypt it somewhere on disk for further reusage? How apps usually story it?

**I will appreciate any HELP!!!**

Comment: Asking the user for their Facebook credentials is not a good idea at all – Facebook says users should never give that data to any third party app (which should be quite obvious).